# Error messages with npm list

Tags: node.js, npm

I ran the this command `npm list -g --depth=0` to list all the global node.js modules installed.

I received some error message. Below are the messages;

```
+-- bower@1.8.2
+-- bower-update-all@0.1.2
+-- browserify@13.3.0
+-- typescript@2.7.2
+-- uglify-js@2.8.29
`-- watchify@3.10.0

npm ERR! invalid: node-gyp@3.4.0 C:\Users\userXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp
npm ERR! missing: path-array@^1.0.0, required by node-gyp@3.4.0
```

Any idea how to fix them?

I am using node.js ver8.9.4, npm ver5.7.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: can you provide more detail infomation, such as npm version?

Comment: crazy_phage, i'm using npm v5.7.1. Edited the question to add that information.

Comment: please reinstall node-gyp and try again.